# Null Pointer Exception in TextView but value is not null

Tags: android, null, textview, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` and I am inflating layouts into it. In the layouts I have textviews, but when I try to change their text values via a button press, the app crashes and the LogCat gives me a `NullPointerExeception` on the line where i am changing the text value of the `TextView`. I have checked the values I am changing the `TextView` to and they are not null. Any idea what I may be doing wrong right off hand?

Code Update:
Code Snippet (Where I initialize TextView and inflate the Layout into the ViewPager):

```
textview_location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_location);

//Adapter Class for ViewPager:
viewpagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
viewpager_weather = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_weather);
//Set the Adapter:
viewpager_weather.setAdapter(viewpagerAdapter);
//Create an initial view to display:
layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

//Inflate a layout:
layout_weatheroverview =(RelativeLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_weatheroverview, null);

//Add the layout view to the ViewPager:
viewpagerAdapter.addView (layout_weatheroverview, 0);
//Notify that there has been data mod:
viewpagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now in the next snippet I simply set a text change and get a null point exeception:

```
textview_location.setText(location);
```

Comment: Post the logcat logs and the code sample of the activity

Comment: `TextView` is not initialized properly giving you NPE

Comment: I do have it initialized...lemme post some code. One moment, thanks guys.

Comment: please include some code and contents of the logcat along with your question too,will be helpful for others to provide you a good and clean explanation for your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If textview_location is in your ViewPager, you can't access an instance of it until you inflate the ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks, I know proper instantiation just the whole figuring Android out step by step is making me make silly errors :-) Thank you for quick response!